# How to configure my Brother MFC 9125cn printer to output on the front tray instead of the back tray?

Tags: windows-7, printer, brother-printer

I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 and Brother Control Center 2.12.3. I have no problems using the printer.

My wife is using Win 7 professional with Control Center 3.

Any idea where I can configure the output tray?

Comment: Have you tried closing the back tray? When it is open the printer thinks you want the paper to go there instead of to the front.

Comment: @CharlieRB That's it man... Do you want to answer it so the question gets marked as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as simple answer, but it is the complete answer.

Close the back tray so it completes the paper path to the front.